# Chaining asynchronous AJAX calls with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I'm using Angularjs and i have made this service with multiples functions that returns promises .

## My AJAX service :

```
angular.module('yoApp')
    .factory('serviceAjax', function serviceAjax($http) {
      return{
      
        configDataSets:function(path){

          return $http.get(path);

        },
        fileList: function(site_url,dataSet,varName,region,date){
          return $http.get(site_url + "mwf/" + dataSet + "/" +varName + "/" + region + "/" + date + "/filelist/");
        },
        config: function(site_url,dataSet){
          return $http.get(site_url + "mwf/" + dataSet + "/config/");
        },

      }});
```

**Controller code**

I have already done something like this but as i may have more requests chained i think that's not the best way to do this :

```
serviceAjax.config(site_url,$scope.dataset).then function(data){
          $scope.config=data.data;
serviceAjax.configDataSets("images/configDatasets.json").then(function(data){

          $scope.configDatasets = data.data;
 
});
});
```

What i want to do is first Call in my controller **config** and then wait for it to finish then call **configDataSets** . what's the best way to do it, i have tried to look at $q and differed but i can't seem to figure out how to do it. Any help would be great!

Comment: see my answer - you can "chain" the `.then` calls without nesting them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `.then` method exposed by the promise:

```
serviceAjax.config(function(response) {
     // use response.data from first call
     ...
}).then(function() {
     return serviceAjax.configDataSets("images/configDatasets.json");
}).then(function(response) {
     // use response.data from second call
     ...
});
```

Also, consider using `$resource` instead of `$http` if your HTTP service follows typical RESTful usage.

Comment: The first call is working but the second one i got an undefined for the response parameter, and i tried reversing the order and each call works for the first time but the second one i got an undefined , my code   serviceAjax.config(site_url,"all").then(function(data){

          console.log(data);

        }).then(serviceAjax.configDataSets("images/configDatasets.json")).then(function(data) {

          console.log(data.data);

        });

Comment: you can't actually pass the result of `serviceAjax.configDataSets("images/configDatasets.json")` into `.then` - you have to pass a function  - I'll amend my answer to show

Comment: Ah i see you need to first return the promise then use the ".then" method thank you very much !